# Temporarily diasble test in Azure pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I need to temporarily disable the test run in the azure pipeline without deleting it from the pipeline complettely. How can i do it ?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this (right-click and Disable)?

[image]

Comment: @Shamari Yes thats the way. Thank you ! That option was unpredictable but was worth the right click. Thank you for the quick reply. guess i have to wait a few minutes to be able to set this as the answer.